# Assertions in C89?

Tags: c89, assertion

I'm writing C89 on MSFT Visual Studio 2010 Beta. How can I make an assertion, similar to Java's `assert` keyword? I think I need to define a macro, but I'm not sure how. (It seems like this is something that's been done before, so I'd rather use that than try to roll my own.)

Here's a guess:

```
int assert(int truth_value) {
   // crash the program with an appropriate error message   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C89 has `<assert.h>`, which contains the macro you're looking for.

```
#include <assert.h>
assert(expression);
```

From the documentation:

> The **assert**() macro tests the given *expression* and if it is false, the
>   calling process is terminated.  A diagnostic message is written to *stderr*
>   and the abort(3) function is called, effectively terminating the program.
>
> If *expression* is true, the **assert**() macro does nothing.

Comment: Yup.  The thing to remember is that `assert()` is usually disabled for production runs, so it's important to make sure *expression* has no effects other than returning a true or false value.

Comment: Yeah, you can disable `assert()` by defining `NDEBUG`.